# Chrome extension manifest.json wildcard for *.jpg

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, match

In my Chrome Extension's manifest.json file I have:

```
"permissions": [
    "https://*/*/*.jpg",
    "storage"
],
```

but it works on all the https urls...

Comment: There's no way because `permissions` applies to the entire site.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have the source of the doc that says that though?

Comment: That's just how the entire API works. The documentation doesn't have an explicit quote you want but it's possible to infer from [various parts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Comment: Thank you, you are most probably right. You can put your comment as an answer for the points though